# Symfony entity repository with many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, repository

I have two entities `product` and `document` which are related via a `many-to-many` relationship with a `JOIN` table. My product entity looks like below, my document entity currently has no reference back to the product.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\MyApp\CmsBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Document")
     * @JoinTable(name="products_documents",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
     protected $documents;

     // ...

     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->documents = new ArrayCollection();
     }

    public function addDocument(Document $document)
    {
        $this->documents[] = $document;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDocument(Document $document)
    {
        $this->documents->removeElement($document);
    }

    public function getDocuments()
    {
        return $this->documents;
    }
```

When I present the product on the front-end of the site I also list it's documents. However I need to be able to filter them out based on their attributes `status` and `privacy`.

So I've been trying to create an entity repository to handle this logic but everything I've tried so far has failed. What I need to achieve is a query similar to this, but in a Symfony/Doctrine format:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM documents d, products_documents pd,
WHERE pd.product_id = :product_id
  AND pd.document_id = d.id,
  AND d.status = 'PUBLISHED',
  AND d.privacy = 'PUBLIC';
```

Ideally I would like to be able to do something as simple as this from my controller:

```
// get documents to display on front-end
$documents = $em->getRepository('MyAppCmsBundle:Product')->getDocumentsForProduct($product);
```

I've got the call to the function working, I'm just not clued up on how to retrieve the data I want.

**UPDATE**

This is what I've got so far, whilst maintaining working code, but instead of returning documents it returns all products. I'm not sure how to add the condition to specify it to the product I pass in, or to return the documents and not the product.

*ProductRepository.php*

```
public function getDocumentsForProduct(Product $product, $authenticated = false)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->join('MyApp\CmsBundle\Entity\Document', 'd')
    ->where('d.status = :status')
    ->andWhere('d.privacy = :privacy')
    ->setParameters(array(
        'status' => 'PUBLISHED',
        'privacy' => 'PUBLIC',
    ))
    ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Update your question with your dql query.  It should be as simple as doing a join on documents and then applying the same where clause.

Comment: @Cerad I've updated it with what I've currently got implemented but it's not a finished solution.

Comment: You will need to add a where condition to limit things to just one product.  Then return $product->getDocuments();  You also want to add a select('d') to avoid lazy loading the documents.  Check the docs on how to build dql's.  It's a key part of using Doctrine 2 effectively.  It's worth taking the time to understand what is happening.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. I can call `$product->getDocuments()` on the entity but then it returns all documents rather than the ones I'd like to filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to return documents, you should put it in your DocumentRepository.

The 'createQueryBuilder' method autmatically selects entities of the type that belongs to the repository. So in your case, that's Product. If you put the same code in the DocumentRepository, you should get Document entities.

I don't know if there is a way to change this using QueryBuilder. But you can use DQL instead like this:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT p FROM YourBundle:Document WHERE ...');
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, I did originally try to use a `DocumentRepository` but ran into trouble there also.

Comment: I've got this far: `$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT d FROM MyAppCmsBundle:Document d WHERE d.status = :status AND d.privacy = :privacy')->setParameters(array('status' => 'PUBLISHED', 'privacy' => 'PUBLIC'));` - not sure where/how to specify the product relation.

Comment: After the SELECT statement: `JOIN d.product p`
But you might have to add a reference back to the product for that, or use the 'ON' clause. See the doctrine manuals for that.

Comment: `product` doesn't exist on `document` though, that's one of the problems. `Document has no association named product`

Comment: K mate, got it now I think. I had to change the type of ORM mapping to `many-to-many bidirectional`.